# In spring web mvc application date value is received as NULL in controller after reading from date-picker on jsp page

Tags: java, jquery, spring, spring-mvc, date-formatting

I have a spring mvc web application that uses jquery. I used the spring tags to map the fields to pojo's directly. So that the date will get mapped to the corresponding field.

In Spring MVC a feild having date picker is reading date in correct format:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#deliveryDate").datepicker({
            minDate: 0
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#quoationStartDate").datepicker({
            minDate: 0
        });
    });
</script>
```

here is the input parameter on JSP:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <i class="icon-calendar-7"></i>
        <label>Actual Delivery On</label>   
        <form:input path="deliveryDate" class="form-control required" id="deliveryDate" name="deliveryDate" type="date" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" />                 
    </div>
</div>
```

Have used @Initbinder to parse date

```
@InitBinder
public void dateBinder(WebDataBinder bind) {
    System.out.println("In Binder");
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
    simpleDateFormat.setLenient(false);
    bind.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(simpleDateFormat, true));
}
```

But after a form post operation the date received in the controller  has value null.
What must be the solution to this so that I will receive a date in format dd-MM-yyyy and this date can be stored into database.

Comment: I found one observation.
Date is read perfectly if I change the type of html input tag from type="Date" to type="text". But if I do so the date picker does not appear.

Is there any better solution to this???

Answer (score 0):

Works after changing html input type from type="Date" to type="text".