# TextboxFor in EditorTemplate does not save value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc-editor-templates, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I'm having trouble with using an EditorTemplate in MVC.

My EditorTemplate looks like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
        });
    });
</script>

<tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Title)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Authors)</td>
    <td><a href="/administration/products/bookz/bookform.aspx?book=@Model.BookId" target="_blank">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ISBN13)</a></td>
    <td>@extPrice.ToString("N2") </td >
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Price, new { data_val_number = "The field Price must be a number." })</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MemberPriceStartDate, "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control datepicker" })</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MemberPriceEndDate, "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control datepicker" })</td>
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.BookId)
</tr>
```

The `@model` is of type `Books` (Books is singular due to a database-messup -_-).

The EditorTemplate is called from the view like so:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model)
```

Where `@model` is of type `IEnumerable<Books>`.

When posted to my controller, `Books.Price` is passed correctly, but `Books.MemberPriceStartDate` and `Books.MemberPriceEndDate` is always null.
The hidden field `Books.BookId` is also passed correctly.

Any ideas as to why that might happen?

EDIT:

Here are the relevant properties on the `Books` object:

```
public Nullable<System.DateTime> MemberPriceStartDate { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.DateTime> MemberPriceEndDate { get; set; }
public Nullable<decimal> Price { get; set; }
public int BookId { get; set; }
```

Comment: First thing is you are saying are you talking about list view/index page by this "@Html.EditorFor(model => model)
Where @model is of type IEnumerable<Books>." 
Second for your editor view try to debug from the controller action in view as if the model. has value  if has value then then remove the date format "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}" and see.

Comment: @DhakaPariBahan I've now checked using Fiddler - The values are posted correctly - this is the string from Fiddler: __RequestVerificationToken=5NlvZ0suitm6E7SS859qIkpuDdGgMxydw37NgY9NMbk04aWwqjTocSXMkstQAHOJ2337Ja8dEE-Hjq01kEExAd8cq7TRaQ51VPSj2WHWY1KPmp7m6jLXBM1u5v7WiLkK0&%5B0%5D.Price=29%2C00&%5B0%5D.MemberPriceStartDate=19-07-2016&%5B0%5D.MemberPriceEndDate=30-07-2016&%5B0%5D.BookId=352757&%5B1%5D.Price=49%2C00&%5B1%5D.MemberPriceStartDate=&%5B1%5D.MemberPriceEndDate=&%5B1%5D.BookId=353782&%5B2%5D.Price=99%2C00&%5B2%5D.MemberPriceStartDate=&%5B2%5D.MemberPriceEndDate=&%5B2%5D.BookId=353583

Comment: What kind of `IEnumerable<Books>` you have? `Html.TextBoxFor` returns string by default, which require explicit casting/parsing to be POST-ed as `DateTime` value. `Html.EditorFor` may suits for handling datetime values.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Changing it to a EditorFor didn't do anything different.Will update original post with the types of the relevant properties.

Comment: debug with visual studio.

Comment: Its almost certainly because the culture in you server does not accept dates in the format `dd-MM-yyyy`. And you should remove the script from your editor template. Duplicate scripts and inline scripts are bad practive. Move the script to you main view or layout

Answer (score 0):

In your model date format for particular field and
 your input date format-"dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'" may mismatch.

Comment: The reason why they're not the same is because of the datePicker javascripy, if I change dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy to dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy - It will show the year 2 times :-)

Comment: Try this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37304922/jquery-datepicker-with-spring-mvc-passing-date-from-view-to-controller-sends-n